# Calling method is not asking for to handle exception when i use throws

Tags: java, throws

Here I have used throws in method signature when i am going to call this method from some where else that is not asking me to handle the exception.

```
 public class Exception {

        int a, b, c;

        void set(String data[]) throws NumberFormatException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
            a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);//convert the string into int. eg1.("12" ---> 12)  eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
            b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            c = 0;
        }

        void divide() throws ArithmeticException {
            c = a / b;
        }

        void disp() {
            System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i am going to call this method from some where else that is not asking me to handle the exception.

Yes, because both are [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)s and must not be caught.

Read the java tutorial about [exceptions and unchecked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Sometimes you see methods that declare `RuntimeException`s, like your method does. It is a way to document the exceptions that might be thrown even if you don't catch them.

**In addition to user3168013's comment**

> how can we able to convert unchecked exception to checked exception .

Every exception can have a cause. A cause is another exception that lead to it. If it has no cause it is a root exception. So you can just create an instance of a checked exception, pass it the unchecked exception as it's cause and throw the checked expection.

For example define your checked exception

```
public class DataFormatException extends Exception {
    public DataFormatException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

and then throw your own

```
void set(String data[]) throws DataFormatException {
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);// convert the string into int.
                                        // eg1.("12"
                                        // ---> 12) eg2.("df23" ---> fail)
        b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        c = 0;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new DataFormatException(e);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new DataFormatException(e);
    }
}
```

Of course it would be better to give a detailed exception message depending on the cause, but this is just a short example.

Comment: How the class user will get know about run time exception and how to handle it.

Comment: You can handle them the same way as checked exceptions. Use a try/catch. The class user will only know that your method throws a RuntimeException if you tell it (javadoc or declare them in the method signature). I would recommend you to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: There can I use throw to handle exception.

Comment: how can we able to convert unchecked exception to checked exception .

Comment: @user3168013 I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: super(cause); here am getting exception.

Comment: @user3168013 what exception do you get?

Comment: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: Throwable
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @user3168013 ok, I guess you put the `DataFormatException` or your own exception in the same package than your example class. Because your example class is named `Exception` it will be used instead of `java.lang.Exception`. Rename your example code `Exception` to `ExceptionExample` or something else or use the full quallified name when you extend from `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: @user3168013 the simplest way is to use `public class DataFormatException extends java.lang.Exception {`

Comment: Ok i got that one can u plz tell me how to use that with out using try catch over there

Comment: There is simply no other way to do it. If a method throws an unchecked exception and you want an checked exception you must catch the unchecked, create a checked exception and throw it.

Comment: public class DataFormatException extends Exception {
    public DataFormatException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
} how will cme to know this will create checked exception.

Comment: You can find the answer in the tutorial link: "Errors and runtime exceptions are collectively known as unchecked exceptions.". So when you extend `Exception` it is a checked exception.

Answer (score 1):

Both Exceptions are  `unchecked Exception`. Unchecked Exception are handled at runtime.

Its developer choice how to handle or not runtime Exception , compiler never force you handle.

Find more on handling  [`Runtime Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3).